# How can I make ascii-banners from the command line?

Tags: command-line

I've seen people using the terminal command: `banner`. This creates big ascii-art-style text.

When I try to run it, however, the terminal says it doesn't exist. Why?

How do I install it? Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to install it before you can use it.
Type in the terminal:

`sudo apt-get install sysvbanner`

This Package is not available in the standard installation and for this is why you have to install it manually.

Answer (score 40):

I've always preferred `figlet` for big writing. Something about it preserves the character shape better. A bit subjective but there you go. Simple enough:

```
$ sudo apt-get install figlet
$ figlet oh hai!
       _       _           _ _ 
  ___ | |__   | |__   __ _(_) |
 / _ \| '_ \  | '_ \ / _` | | |
| (_) | | | | | | | | (_| | |_|
 \___/|_| |_| |_| |_|\__,_|_(_)
```

(It looks better in a terminal than it does here)

There are a ton of formatting options too that make it suitable for lots of different situations. It does this through "fonts" (`standard`, `slant`, `shadow`, `small`, `smslant`, `bubble`, `digital`, `mini`,  etc). `man figlet` has a full listing of available styles and formatting options but here are a few examples:

```
$ figlet -f slant Hooah!
    __  __                  __    __
   / / / /___  ____  ____ _/ /_  / /
  / /_/ / __ \/ __ \/ __ `/ __ \/ / 
 / __  / /_/ / /_/ / /_/ / / / /_/  
/_/ /_/\____/\____/\__,_/_/ /_(_)   

$ figlet -f smslant Hooah!
   __ __               __   __
  / // /__  ___  ___ _/ /  / /
 / _  / _ \/ _ \/ _ `/ _ \/_/ 
/_//_/\___/\___/\_,_/_//_(_)  

$ figlet -f bubble Hooah!
  _   _   _   _   _   _  
 / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ 
( H | o | o | a | h | ! )
 \_/ \_/ \_/ \_/ \_/ \_/ 

$ figlet -f mini Hooah!

|_| _  _  _.|_ | 
| |(_)(_)(_|| |o
```

Comment: Both of you used the same command at the same time , so cant decide whose first. Any way Thank you for answering. +1

Comment: look at my new answer , you can find something really cool

Comment: You are a treasure-trove of knowledge!  Installed 190 KB package...  ;-)

Comment: figlet usually comes packaged with the `showfigfonts` tool that output font samples.

Comment: Figlet doesn't seem to be available on WLS :/ `apt search figlet` gives me nothing

Comment: @MarcoPanichi It's in the Ubuntu "universe" repo. I'm not sure if that's enabled on WLS but if it's not, run `sudo add-apt-repository universe`, update and try again.

Comment: Thank you @Oli, I solved doing `apt update`

Answer (score 15):

If you wish to use other "fonts" / ASCII art for a banner, you could also look at figlet:

```
sudo apt-get install figlet

foo@bar:~$ figlet
hi
 _     _
| |__ (_)
| '_ \| |
| | | | |
|_| |_|_|
```

cheers

sc.

Comment: Both of you used the same command at the same time , so cant decide whose first. Any way Thank you for answering. +1

Comment: does he look like he needs the points? ;-)

Comment: look at my new answer you can find something really cool\

Comment: http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=testall&f=Graffiti&t=Test for figlets...

Answer (score 14):

Found one more named as toilet.

```
sudo apt-get install toilet
```

Then run

```
toilet -f bigmono9 -F gay <your string>
```

For Example:

[image]

Comment: that's a good suggestion, had never heard of that.  thanks.

Comment: looks like toilet-paper to me. Colorful at that.

Answer (score 5):

**Alternative** 
(without installing anything)

1. Go to https://duckduckgo.com
2. In search bar type: `figlet YOUR BANNER HERE`
3. Copy the figlet and use it in the Bash script

Example Bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "
    YOUR FIGLET BANNER HERE
"
```

Answer (score 4):

Open your terminal and paste as

```
 sudo apt-get install sysvbanner
```

Usage:

```
 banner <yourstring>
```

Example:

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Intersting, what would I be used for? Just wondering...

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness   where ever you want , for example in bash scripts # stands for commenting & there you can have your identity.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness printers! We used to use this to create banners for printers and put some fancy info on the 1st page.

Comment: I'm a fan of the sysvbanner source. its 160 lines of C, and most of that is an array of 7x8 glyphs. you or anyone could simply make an alternate. I just moded the underscore to be blank, and the max line length to be 20, then I can write longer banners with underscores showing up as spaces. I wonder if I can feed it ascii arts like nyancat to make Huge nyancat banners.

Answer (score 0):

Another (longer) option that might be helpful if there's any nodejs involvement is [`ascii-banner`](https://npmjs.org/package/ascii-banner). It's a node library but it can be scripted out.

```
$ sudo apt-get install npm
$ sudo npm -g install ascii-banner
$ node -e "var AsciiBanner = require('ascii-banner');AsciiBanner.write('Oh hai').out();"
  ______    __    __      __    __       ___       __  
 /  __  \  |  |  |  |    |  |  |  |     /   \     |  | 
|  |  |  | |  |__|  |    |  |__|  |    /  ^  \    |  | 
|  |  |  | |   __   |    |   __   |   /  /_\  \   |  | 
|  `--'  | |  |  |  |    |  |  |  |  /  _____  \  |  | 
 \______/  |__|  |__|    |__|  |__| /__/     \__\ |__|
```

It also has font options:

```
$ node -e "require('ascii-banner').write('Oh hai').font('Thin').out();"

,---.|        |         o
|   ||---.    |---.,---..
|   ||   |    |   |,---||
`---'`   '    `   '`---^`
```

Comment: Long but okay , what are the features ?

Comment: https://npmjs.org/package/ascii-banner#readme — `.color(...)` and alignment and `before(...)` and `after(...)` (again, with alignment and colour) arguments.