# Command-line presentation tool for Linux?

Tags: command-line, presentation

In a few days I am going to give a presentation about Linux.
So I want to show Linux in style.
So I want any tool for presentation. I heard about [Mdp](http://xmodulo.com/presentation-command-line-linux.html).

[image: Few screenshot]

Now I want to make my own.
How can I create this type of slide?

Comment: The page you link to has several good examples. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Jos I want to increase size of tittle. number for content on single page :)

Comment: @Jos I have no idea how to use it  : '->' '*_' '---------'

Comment: As this runs inside a terminal window, you can't control the font size, but I suppose you could build letters out of white blocks (like the rectangle on page 6).  As on how to use the different modifiers, I found [this page](http://www.robertmuench.ch/development/projects/mdp/documentation/).

Comment: @Ashu you can number the content by typing the number in begging the line like `1 Multi-level headers`, `2 Code block formatting` but I don't think so you can enlarge the font size.

Comment: Please be aware that you linked to a third party article on it, not official documentation. Official documentation can be found from the [github](https://github.com/visit1985/mdp/blob/master/sample.md). Another thing to note that is it's still in alpha status. So features are bound to be missing.

Comment: @Ashu please [edit] your question with the additional information - in comments it gets lost.

Answer (score 15):

In MDP, you're limited to what the console can do. Console text monospace and impossible to change its size on a character-by-character basis. That's sort of the point of this. You do have a couple of options to make it a better presentation though:

1. Increase the global font size in the terminal (in Konsole this is <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>). This makes it easier to read at a distance but will limit how many rows you can fit on the screen. MDP will bug out if the font size is too big for the content.
2. Use ASCII art! [`figlet` is pretty great](https://askubuntu.com/a/392081/449) for this but you will have to use the markdown code-formatting to preseve the spacing around it in your presentation file.

   ```
    __  __         _____ _ _   _      _ 
   |  \/  |_   _  |_   _(_) |_| | ___| |
   | |\/| | | | |   | | | | __| |/ _ \ |
   | |  | | |_| |   | | | | |_| |  __/_|
   |_|  |_|\__, |   |_| |_|\__|_|\___(_)
           |___/
   ```

Ultimately it's going to be a combination of the two.

`mdp` really looks like fun though, just make sure you test it on the presentation hardware *before* you do your presentation - you don't want to be the muppet whose presentation doesn't work. It might make sense to make a screenshot-PDF backup.

Answer (score 14):

[`TOIlet`](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/toilet) prints text using large characters made of smaller characters. It is similar in many ways to [`FIGlet`](http://www.figlet.org/) with additional features such as Unicode handling, colour fonts, filters and various export formats.

Install it fonts :

```
sudo apt-get install toilet toilet-fonts
```

screenshot:

[image]

---

From [man toilet](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/toilet.1.html):

```
-f, --font <name>
    Use the given font instead of the default value. Fonts are .flf or .tlf files 
    stored in the '/usr/share/figlet' directory. Fonts are looked first in the font directory, 
    then in the current directory.
```

Available filters:

```
$ toilet  --filter list

"crop": crop unused blanks
"gay": add a rainbow colour effect
"metal": add a metallic colour effect
"flip": flip horizontally
"flop": flip vertically
"180": rotate 180 degrees
"left": rotate 90 degrees counterclockwise
"right": rotate 90 degrees clockwise
"border": surround text with a border
```

Comment: How to use this in mdp ?